# Overview-Lines update record AX 2009

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I am trying to update a delivery date of a record in Overview part of a form and I want that the Lines part of this record stays the same,but when I do the job to update the date, the date changes but the line part of this dissapear.As far as I know I should update also the table which Lines parttake the data but the 2 select for Updates insde one job are not working.ANy suggestion?
Thank you

Comment: Can you give more context, e.g. are you talking about sales lines? And could you some of your code that you have written so far?

Comment: Is the system set up to always update order lines? For example, for sales orders, is Accounts Receivable / Parameters / Updates / Update Order Lines / Update Ship and receipt dates set to 'Always', 'Never', or 'Prompt'?